What word should I use when I want to refer to the different roads that are drawn from one city to other cities and connect them?
I am writing an article about ways to connect an ancient city with cities of the same time. But because these roads were paved or made of dirt, maybe a special word should be used for it.Which of these words should I use? road, track, way, path,route

Are you asking if 'road' can be used about routes which are both paved and unpaved?

They're trunk roads / routes.

Many roads are not paved and are made of dirt, still today.

In general, road is fine to use for any human-made connector between places that is created to allow for people and vehicles to move more easily (and that is not a canal or a specialized track for some sort of vehicle like a train). It doesn't matter whether it is paved or simply compacted dirt.
Roads are also defined somewhat by the definition of their time. So if the above definition suits how people at the time would have used or considered it, it can be referred to as a road today.
In general, if soldiers or merchants used it, road is likely the right term.
Track, Path, and Trail
All of these carry connotations of being either less formally maintained or of being smaller or less commonly used.
If you called this connector a path, a reader may assume that it is narrow and cannot fit many people at the same time or larger vehicles like carts pulled by animals. It might be rarely used, or only commonly used by a single person. Or, it might be very short, such as the path between a house and a well.
If you call it a track, a reader may assume that it is not human-made at all, but instead created by animals (such as a "game track"). If it was created by humans, it may not have been so intentionally, but rather just if someone walked the same way again and again, a track would form.
If you call it a trail, it may have the same connotation as track or it may mean that the terrain is rugged or difficult to pass through in some way. It is also likely narrow.
Route
Route describes how to get from one place to another, and may involve traveling on many roads. For example:

The Roman armies had to carefully consider their route toward modern-day France.
The spy took a complicated route through the market to ensure she wasn't followed.

In modern America, you may also hear roads referred to as Route [number]. These are sets of roads and directions that the government has officially recognized as commonly traveled. They are usually not a single road, but rather a set of well-marked turns.
Way
Way is not commonly used in AmE with one exception - some streets will have it in their name (eg., "Cherry Way" or "Robin Way"). These are usually (although not always) residential streets, and are still referred to as roads or streets rather than "ways." For example, you won't hear a native speaker say "Turn onto the way up there." They would say "Turn onto the the street up there - the one called Robin Way."

Road is used for trains and ships.

If it was between cities it was a road, even though we know that it would be nothing like a modern road.
A path is for walking on (or, in modern times, sometimes cycling).
A route is the way you get to another place (e.g. what towns or geographical features you pass through), not the surface you are travelling on.

So if I'm talking about a road network between cities, can I use route?

Yes, a network of roads or routes.

'Road' is a very general term, applying to railways and the sea too, as well as figuratively: the road to ... hell / riches etc.
